# Flash AS3 preloader doesn't show until 100%

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, preloader, flash-cc

I realize this have been asked and answered numerous times but even after some reading I can't fix the issue.
What I have:
A preloader
A game which should happen after the preloader
What really happens:
All the components load before the preloader, which kind of makes the preloader useless haha. I've changed "Export classes in frame 1" to "frame 2", but to no avail.
I would prefer not to use an external preloader.

Here's my code:

```
   stop();

 this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);

 function loading(e:Event):void{

    var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

    preloader.scaleX = loaded/total;

 if (total == loaded){
    nextFrame();
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
}

}
```

And here's this:

https://pp.vk.me/c630919/v630919494/37371/sgdJTWian6Q.jpg

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to set break points in your code and run the debugger? If you can do that you will probably solve it yourself. I always trace values to the output window as well.

Comment: @NealDavis Well, I generally trace `"1"` in JS, when having lazy. Are you executing this in a class?

Comment: Make sure you only have your preloader on frame 1, nothing else. And make sure you don't export the assets from your library to frame 1. Flash will ALWAYS load the first frame before doing anything so something is still in there

Comment: There are two things you should check. First is determine frame size, if your frame 1 is 99% of the SWF, you did something wrong. If it's small but the problem persists, I am aware of IE11 behavior that first fully loads the SWF, and only then displays Flash player window, rendering preloader useless. I am not aware of other browsers behave as such, but it can be a trend.

Comment: are you testing by loading the swf directly? if that's the case, try to embed it in a html page

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add listener with this.root.loaderInfo (this way is better though your way works in this condition,so never mind).

1. No need to change "export classes in frame 1 => 2", just keep the default value;
2. First frame code can be like this:
   `import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
   this.root.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,loaderProgressHandler);
   function loaderProgressHandler(evt:ProgressEvent):void
   {
       preloader.scaleX = evt.bytesLoaded /evt.bytesTotal;
   }`
3. Second frame(you actually wanna show) code like this:
   `stop();`
4. That's all.Maybe you can't see the progress clearly because local simulation speed is too fast. You can try "Simulate Download" with shutcut "Ctrl + Enter" twice.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid messing up with class export frames, I usually use a second SWF to preload. It works perfectly. You just need to make sure you clear all memory in the loader movie once the large SWF is loaded.
In this way you can keep a super simplified pre-loader. In some projects I just used the same pre-loader for in game server connection waiting times. It is versatile and doesn't bother your main app logic.